# multiline text, sqlite and uitextview, is not working

Tags: iphone, sqlite, nsstring, uitextview

I tried many things, i can't display multiline texts from database into uitextview, the \n characters appear as they are instead creating new lines.

```
NSString *aDescription2 = [NSString stringWithCString:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

The problem must be here, because if i hardcode the nsstring with some \n they work.

I also tried to replace the \n with something else, just for testing. The \n chars are not replaced at all

```
NSString *aDescription = [aDescription2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"-------"];
```

What's happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried a different encoding, instead of `NSUTF8StringEncoding`?

Seems that the newline character is being replaced by something other than a newline and your `stringByReplacing` can't find them since it is looking for a newline.  I suspect that maybe `NSUTF8StringEncoding` is escaping your `\` and the `n` so that you get those two characters instead of a newline.

Comment: I tried almost all encodings, but you're right with something, \ was escaped, so now i'm replacing \\n instead \n, with a \n and works.
Anyway, if there's another solution without replacing occurrences i'd like to hear. Maybe is something wrong with the database?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the database escapes the \n.  Can you check that?

Comment: When i'm creating the sqlite i'm executing sql queries with the .read command from a database exported from phpmyadmin. each new line is represented with \r\n. Someone suggested to do something like this:  insert into t values('ana are' || x'0a' || 'mere');
I'll try that soon.